# dual boot problem Ubuntu14.04 and Windows 7 - windows won't start

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7

I have problem with Ubuntu's bootloader. Ubuntu works fine, but when I try loading Windows, my screen goes half-black, half-purple with some semi-horizontal white lines, or just purple with those lines:

[image]

This has been happening since the beginning, but removing the battery and starting computer again solved the problem at first, then later using a `boot-repair` CD solved the problem, but now nothing works and I just can't get it to load windows. Here's boot summary info if it will help: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7741166/

Windows 7 is 64bit.

Comment: This is not really "a problem" IMHO :-) By the way, what is your laptop ?

Comment: XD I need windows, I have some tools I can't use on ubuntu, or at least I don't know how. Anyway, my laptop is toshiba satellite c55.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Grub-loader file gets corrupted. if the files goes missing, the BIOS will not be able to find where the Os is in the hard-disk. which i know is very embarrassing and occurs very frequently.. try a windows repair cd. And things should be fine once again (at least for windows).. Good luck..

Comment: Now I am going to ask a question which is probably stupid and has simple answer but I can't find it...how do I get windows repair CD? Google says it can be created from windows, but I can't get into windows so...

Comment: well, like they say, NO questions are stupid.. if there were, web sites like these would not exist.. :) anyways.. this should help you..
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/start-your-computer-from-a-windows-7-installation-disc-or-usb-flash-drive

and this too..